# L'Hospital's Rule Application for $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} (\frac{x}{x+1})^x$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Is there a simple way to evaluate

$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} (\frac{x}{x+1})^x$

using L'Hospital's rule?

My level is multi-variable calculus.

Comment: Mathjax tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: using $y=1/x$, write it as $\exp\left[-\lim_{y\to0^+}\frac{\ln(1+y)}{y}\right]$. However, by that route you can just use the definition of a derivative.

Comment: The simplest way would be to use the definition of $e$. L'Hopital would take you much longer.

Comment: You should try substituting $y=x+1$ & then substituting $z=-y$ , to get "Something" involving the "Definition" of $e$ , then you might easily make the Over-All Evaluation , in terms of $e$ itself.

Comment: Why do you insist on using L'Hopital? This is overkill. I agree with J.G.'s and NinadMunshi's comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y(x):=\left(\frac x{x+1}\right)^x\implies\ln y(x) = \frac{\ln\frac x{x+1}}{\frac1x}$$

Now, as $x\to\pm\infty,$ the numerator and denominator above tend to $0,$ and the quotient of their derivatives is
$$\frac{\frac1{x(x+1)}}{-\frac1{x^2}}=-\frac x{x+1}=-1+\frac1{x+1}\to-1.$$

We can now derive successively the (existence and) value of the following limits:
$$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\ln y(x)=-1\quad [\text{by L'Hospital  rule}]$$
$$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}y(x)=e^{-1}\quad [\text{by continuity of }\exp].$$

Comment: You are welcome. I think we (including @AlvinL) can delete our comments now.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac x{x+1}\right)^x&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\exp\left(x\log{\frac{x}{x+1}}\right)\\&=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\log\frac x{x+1}}{\frac1x}\right)\\&=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x(x+1)}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)\\&=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}-\frac{x}{x+1}\right)\\&=e^{-1}.\end{align}$$

Comment: How did you get rid of the log(I.e. what property/theorem)?

And specifically by log do you mean ln?

Comment: L'hospital's rule. That's what you asked for @Pheonix

Comment: I think this later answer should be deleted, as it is redundant with [the accepted one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4775181), and less rigoroulsy written (writing equalities *before* proving the existence of the limits involved).

Comment: I don't get why it should be removed. I just tried to prove the same answer, without writing anything as it was all obvious. He wanted to prove this by L'hopital and I didn't want to "complicate" my answer with words and explanations - what's the problem exactly? Because even if not for the reader, then ofr other people who seek the asnewr to this question

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to find the limit of $\log\left ({x\over x+1}\right )^x=x\log{x\over x+1}.$ Substitute $y={1\over x}.$ Then
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x\log{x\over x+1}=-\lim_{y\to 0^+}{\log (1+y)\over y}\overset{H}{=}-\lim_{y\to 0^+}{1\over 1+y}=-1$$ Hence the original limit is equal $e^{-1}.$ Actually the middle limit is equal $$-{d\over dy}\log(1+y)\mid_{y=0}=-{1\over 1+y}\mid_{y=0}=-1$$ so the Hospital rule is not needed, just the derivative suffices.

The limit can be calculated basing on the definition of $e$ with no application of the  differential calculus
$$\left ({x\over x+1}\right )^x=\left (1+{1\over x}\right )^{-x}\underset{x\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} e^{-1}$$